# Returning arrays in php causes syntax error

Tags: php

```
function get_arr() {
    return array("one","two","three");
}

echo get_arr()[0];
```

Why does the above code throw the following error?

```
parse error: syntax error, unexpected '['
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Array Syntax Parse Error Left Square Bracket "\["](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11912233/php-array-syntax-parse-error-left-square-bracket)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is simply a limitation of PHP's syntax. You cannot index a function's return value if the function returns an array. There's nothing wrong with your function; rather this shows the homebrewed nature of PHP. Like a katamari ball it has grown features and syntax over time in a rather haphazard fashion. It was not thought out from the beginning and this syntactical limitation is evidence of that.

Similarly, even this simpler construct does not work:

```
// Syntax error
echo array("one", "two", "three")[0];
```

To workaround it you must assign the result to a variable and then index the variable:

```
$array = get_arr();
echo $array[0];
```

Oddly enough they got it right with objects. `get_obj()->prop` is syntactically valid and works as expected. Go figure.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to actually confirm my suspicion.

Comment: +1 for Katamari reference <3, Also you can cast your array to an object `return (object) $result` PHP documentation: "Arrays convert to an object with properties named by keys, and corresponding values." http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php

Answer (score 2):

You can't directly reference returned arrays like that. You have to assign it to a temporary variable.

```
$temp = get_arr();
echo $temp[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

"because you can't do" that isn't a very satifying answer. But that's the case. You can't do `function_which_returns_array()[$offset];` You have to store the return value in a $var and then access it.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure if you do :

```
$myArray = get_arr();
echo $myArray[0];
```

That it will works. You cannot use braket directly.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, you are not the only one to want such a feature enhancement:  PHP Bug report [#45906](http://bonsai.php.net/bug.php?id=45906)

Answer (score 0):

you can also do

```
 list($firstElement) = get_arr();
```