# PHP Array Syntax Parse Error Left Square Bracket "["

Tags: php, arrays, function, reference

I have a function that returns an array.  I have another function that just returns the first row, but for some reason, it makes me use an intermediate variable, i.e. this fails:

```
function f1(/*some args*/) {
    return /*an array*/;
}
function f2(/*some args*/) {
    return f1(/*some args*/)[0];
}
```

. . . with:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in util.php on line 10

But, this works:

```
function f1(/*some args*/) {
    return /*an array*/;
}
function f2(/*some args*/) {
    $temp = f1(/*some args*/);
    return $temp[0];
}
```

I wasn't able to find anything pertinent online (my searches kept getting confused by people with "?", "{", "<", etc.).

I'm self-taught in PHP - is there some reason why I can't do this directly that I've missed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to reference a specific element of an anonymous array in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8276224/is-it-possible-to-reference-a-specific-element-of-an-anonymous-array-in-php)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access PHP array element with a function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/396519/access-php-array-element-with-a-function)

Comment: The language doesn't allow it until 5.4.0

Comment: Even though this is old, I thought I'd leave a comment. You can return index 0 if you use `current`, like so: `return current( f1(/*some args*/) );`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can't use function array dereferencing

```
return f1(/*some args*/)[0];
```

until [PHP 5.4.0](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php) and above.

Comment: props for revealing the proper term for this, it ended a long search for what should have been a simple question.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this behavior is that PHP functions can't be chained like JavaScript functions can be. Just like `document.getElementsByTagNames('a')[0]` is possible.

You have to stick to the second approach for PHP version < 5.4

> Function array dereferencing has been added, e.g. foo()[0].

http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php