# PHP FastCGI Parse error

Tags: php, nginx, fastcgi

I'm getting the following error message in log:

```
2014/08/05 00:13:18 [error] 816#0: *23 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Parse
error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /var/www/example.php on line 32" while reading
response header from upstream, client: 1.1.1.1, server: example.com, request: "GET
/example.php HTTP/1.1",upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/dev/shm/php-fpm-www.sock:", host:
"example.com"
```

The example.php line 32 is:

```
return $fb->api('/me/scores/','GET')['data'][0]['score'];
```

I've restarted php5-fpm (I'm using PHP 5.3), nginx and the Ubuntu server itself with no luck. Any idea what is going on? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the problem is that you can't use function array deferencing, that is the square brackets after a function call. From PHP 5.4 you can. See also this question [PHP Array Syntax Parse Error Left Square Bracket "["](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11912233/php-array-syntax-parse-error-left-square-bracket)

So try to assign the result of the function call to a variable, and the use it. Like this:

```
$response = $fb->api('/me/scores/','GET');
return $response['data'][0]['score'];
```

Comment: thought that might be the case, how could I do it in PHP 5.3 for that line?

Comment: Ah! Perfect and makes complete sense :) Thank you! Can accept the answer in 6 minutes, thanks again Claudio.

Comment: I have added a sample code of a simple workaround. It should work, try it and let me know.