# Php square brackets syntax error

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp, square-bracket

on my localhost [PHP Version 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.5] this code is working:

```
array($userName => ['score' => $score]);
```

and also this code is working:

```
$this->Auth->user()['id']
```

but on production server [PHP Version 5.3.3-7+squeeze23] in both cases I've got an error:

> Error: Fatal Error (4): syntax error, unexpected '['

what's going on? how can I fix it in a simplest way? (cause changing all arrays in project is highly impracticable and I'm even not sure how to manage the second case with Auth...)

Comment: Read this: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php `[]` it for php 5.4 and higher just use: `array($userName => array('score' => $score));`

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11912233/php-array-syntax-parse-error-left-square-bracket

Comment: yup, it's a good explanation of the second case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first is because [the new `[]` syntax for instantiating arrays only works in 5.4 and above](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php). So, replace it with `array()`:

```
// 5.4+ only:
array($userName => ['score' => $score]);
// 5.3 (and earlier) and 5.4+
array($userName => array('score' => $score));
```

The second is a different 5.4 feature, that of [accessing arrays returned from functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13109/php-access-array-value-on-the-fly), where you should use a temporary variable:

```
// 5.4+ only:
$this->Auth->user()['id']
// 5.3 (and earlier) and 5.4+:
$result = $this->Auth->user()
$result[id]
```

Or, for preference, upgrade your production server to a PHP version that's a bit more modern than the four-or-five year old version you're using. To save on more of these headaches, you either need to do that or start developing locally in 5.3. (If you need to do the latter, I'd look into virtualising your development setup, so you could develop in a virtual box against 5.3 for older production systems.)

Comment: big thanks for solution! (especially the second one :) )

Answer (score 3):

That syntax isn't supported until php version `5.4`

You can see that here:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: ok, now it's clear. thanks a lot!
...in fact I was afraid of this answer. the night with fixing arrays is in front of me ;/

Answer (score 1):

The squarebracket Syntax for Arrays was introduced in php v. 5.4. Same goes for the usage of returned values of a function or method